# Git error: Changes not staged for commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have my project + RestKit submodule. Error appeared when I changed RestKit settings. I added support armv6 and armv7 architecture.

```
git add .
git add -u 
git commit -m "new"
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   RestKit (modified content)
#
```

How to fix this error.

UPDATE: I don't run git add RestKit.

UPDATE2: The strusture of my project is:

[image]

I added submodule as

```
git submodule update -i
```

Comment: what if you don't do `git add -u` (so just `git add .` and `git commit -m 'message'`)

Comment: Have you run `git add RestKit`?

Comment: It didn't helped me too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are apparently dealing with a submodule, so you should use the submodule workflow :

```
# Modification on RestKit, for instance :
cd RestKit
git add .
git commit -m "Support for armv6 & armv7"
cd ..
# RestKit submodule up-to-date, now update your project
git add RestKit
git commit -m "RestKit submodule updated"
```

You can find more information [here](http://speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html).

Also : [Git Book on Submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)

Comment: Could you give us more information then? What is the status of your submodule and of your project?

Comment: This totally helped me too. Had issue with a submodule.