# git: fatal: reference is not a tree. I run git submodule update -i

Tags: git

The structure of my project is:

[image]

I added RestKit as submodule.

When I run git submodule update -i I get an error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: da5895a5e0d1f827ccc0b94a0fe51f385875b4f8
Unable to checkout 'da5895a5e0d1f827ccc0b94a0fe51f385875b4f8' in submodule path 'RestKit'
```

How to fix this error?

UPDATE: I added my submodule as

```
git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
```

This error(reference is not a tree) appears after fixing [Changes not staged for commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488887/git-error-changes-not-staged-for-commit)

Comment: How did you add the RestKit as submodule?

Answer (score 4):

`git submodule init` and `git submodule update` are to be run when you clone a project that has submodules so that you can get the submodules content. It is not for running it the repo where you added the project.

Also, if you were trying trying to do the update in a clone, it seems like you have made your own checkin to RestKit submodule and haven't published ( of course, in this case I suppose you won't have access to push to it ) and the submodule init will fail because the commit that you have made is not available to the clone.

Read here for details of submodule mechanics: http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html