# How to remove the message "Changes not staged for commit:" for submodule

Tags: ios, git, github, afnetworking, git-submodules

We used the AFNetworking as the sub module via git-submodule command. After updated in one branch, we always got the message once switching branches.

> Changes not staged for commit:

What is the root cause and how to fix it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
git add .
```

and then

```
git commit
```

Commands.

Please check these [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721624/github-changes-not-staged-for-commit) and [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488887/git-error-changes-not-staged-for-commit) threads.