# Create Repo on Git and push existing code

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have a git repository (v1) I was working off, pushing, pulling, merging etc.  The problem I have is I made a bit of a mess of this repository and now I need to create a second (v2).  This I have done through bitbucket, however, I need to push the project I was working on (local) with the original repository to the new repository v2.

When I use the command `git init` it just reinitialises the old repo.  So basically I need to start afresh and commit all my source to the new repository.  Could anyone help me on this.  I must add I also wish to keep the existing repository on bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
git remote rename origin v1
git remote add origin {{your Bitbucket repo address}}
git push origin master
```

This way you will keep your existing repository but by default, you will be pushing new commits to the new one.

EDIT:
If you don't need to keep your local repo history, but just the source code, just remove .git catalog, and then try `git init`.

Comment: hi, sorry, I don't see any .gitcatalog files anywhere.   So you suggest put the command `git remote rename origin v1`  followed by `git remote add origin {{your Bitbucket repo address}}`  which repo should I add? v2 I'm guessing?

Comment: {{your Bitbucket repo}} - I meant the new one. I don't know what OS are you using, but .git might be hidden, so use `ls -al` on Linux, or enable hidden catalogs on Windows to see it.

Comment: hi, I'm using mac osx.  Also I've got submodules also, will this alter things?

Comment: AFAIK submodules will not be affected if you don' delete their respective .git catalogs. Your question was a bit chaotic, I still don't know whether you want to keep your repo history or start a new one with the most recent version of source code.

Comment: Sorry about the original question, I was trying to explain the situation.  I want to start a new repository and commit the full project to it (with the most recent code).  I need to share all source with a co worker, and the old repository, like my question is chaotic!

Comment: If the most recent code is enough, either remove the .git catalog or move all visible contents of your repository to a new catalog and init your new repository there.

Comment: Thank you for your help, so yes, my most recent code is what I wish to commit to a new remote repo.  So I created a new folder locally and copied my source there, then I called `git init` which initialised an empty git repository...so after I added by calling `git add .` I then tried to commit, however I get a message `changes not staged for commit **** (modified content)` .  Have you come across this before?

Comment: Instead of using `git add .`, use `git add *`, so that git knows which files to track (and you mean all of them). Then you can commit and push changes to new repo. Either way, I suggest you do some reading on Git, because you seem to lack some basic knowledge and https://git-scm.com/doc has some straightforward description.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I get the same message  - with this `(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)`

Comment: Is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488887/git-error-changes-not-staged-for-commit any helpful for you? This might deal with your submodule problems.