# git Error: "Changes not staged for commit:"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to push my data to my bitbucket repository and i keep on getting an error: Changes not staged for commit.

I use `git add .` to add all the files in my project.

then i use `git commit -m "..."`

and i still receive this error:

```
    On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   src/modules/paypal (new commits)

no changes added to commit
```

I tried to use the solution suggested in below issue, but it didn't work since if I go back to my original project location and try to push it I still receive the same error and if I try to push it from src/modules/paypal I receive a message asking for my git username and password, but my repository is in bitbucket so obviously it didn't work.

[Git error: Changes not staged for commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488887/git-error-changes-not-staged-for-commit)

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't actually have any changes staged. :)

`src/modules/paypal` is a submodule, i.e. a separate Git repository mapped into your main repository. The workflow for these is a fair bit different - you can't just commit changes inside a submodule into your main repo. It works more like this:

1. Commit the changes into the included repo, preferrably in a separate clone of that sub-repo
2. Push them so you can get the new version in your main repo
3. Update the submodule in your main repo (e.g. by pulling while inside it)
4. Update your main repo to point to a different version of the submodule: `git add src/modules/paypal` (you update the submodule reference, not its contents!)
5. Commit

This process obviously only works if you control the original location of the included repo - if you don't, it gets more complicated.

In your case, you have new local commits inside the submodule, and in theory that means you can go straight to step 4 in the list above, but unless those new commits exist in the upstream location for the submodule, anyone else trying to update their copy of your main repo won't be able to update their submodules.